How do I resolve timeout error when pulling in a large object from Salesforce
I will preface this by saying that I am new to PowerBI, but experienced in Salesforce. I am trying to pull in several objects into a PowerBI report by going to Get Data>Salesforce Objects>Custom.
The problem I'm having is that there are hundreds of thousands of rows related to the specifc object I am trying to pull in. I understand that this is an error we get when (the DB or PowerBI? Not sure) times out (the timeout occurs after about 5-10 min of trying to pull in the object):

Does anyone know the best way to solve this problem, specifically related to Salesforce? I read that I should adjust the timeout settings in the DB I'm pulling from (in this case, Salesforce), but I'm not too sure how to do this.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Use XL-Connector or XL-Connector 365. They work fast and reliably with up to 1,048,000 records (that's Excel row limit), and they can move the data both down and up the pipeline.
Disclaimer: I work for Xappex, the maker of XL-Connector
